# This program cannot display the webpage:

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

This program cannot display the webpage: While trying to run an example project I am getting this response in the tomcat server. I dont know how to solve it. Can you help guys?

```
Sep 29, 2013 11:46:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance
in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;D:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card;C:\Program Files\VDownloader;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Apache Ant-1.9.2\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin;.

Sep 29, 2013 11:46:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property
'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:quickstart' did not find a matching 
property.

Sep 29, 2013 11:47:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]

Sep 29, 2013 11:47:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Sep 29, 2013 11:47:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1395 ms

Sep 29, 2013 11:47:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal 
INFO: Starting service Catalina

Sep 29, 2013 11:47:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType
overrides final method getReturnedClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1956)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1919)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1806)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1765)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1751)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1255)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType overrides

final method getReturnedClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
```

It seems you have un-supported version of Hibernate (or) it's dependency jars in classpath. [See this jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6284) if it helps.

Comment: So, if i get all the latest versions Hibernate dependency in my classpath then should that work?

Comment: @facebook-100003643032349: Make sure latest versions are compatible with your runtime, if they are everything should go fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.jboss.org/tattletale to check your classpath. According to this [Hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2442832) entry you can also have multiple incompatible Hibernate-xxx.jar libraries on your classpath.

Also from my inspection this can be a issue with the security manager since the code tries to overwrites (overshadows) a method which is marked as final. Therefore the security manager seams to detect a potential attempt to overcome a java security measure (not being able to replace a final method within a sub-class).

Check if you use incompatible versions of hibernate since the class this happen to is from the hibernate source.